# attachMovie from loadVariablesNum

Tags: flash, variables, actionscript-2, flash-cs5

I am loading a variable at frame 1with `loadVariablesNum("text.txt", 0);`. The variable is called `dayDate` and for this is example the value is `09`.

I have a `movieClip` called `d09` in my library that I would like to attach to an empty `movieClip` (instance name: `myLoader`) via the variable value.

I can load it the "normal" way like this `myLoader.attachMovie("d09", "d09", 1);`

But how do I get my variable-value into that statement? I've tried putting in the variable name (like `myLoader.attachMovie("dayDate", "d09", 1);`) but it just won't do what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used AS2 in a while so I'm not sure what those parameters to attachMovie mean. However I believe you'd want to construct the string "d09" like so: "d" + dayDate

So your code would look something like:

```
myLoader.attachMovie("d" + dayDate, "d09", 1);
```

(Incidentally, by "the value is 09" I'm guessing you mean datDate is the string "09". If you simply mean the number 9 then you'll have to add in the leading 0.)

Comment: Thanks - but this only worked after I installed a `gotoAndPlay(1)` in frame #2. Why is it that I cannot grab the variable at once?

Comment: Found a "swonking"-method at actionscript.org but the if/else run doesn't work... And I have and idea there are niftyer ways to stop process before the variable has loaded. Tips would be appreciated. Or maybe that's for another question.